# I have an i3 5005u cpu, and an intel Hd graphics 5500 gpu, so which one should i use to render a 3d animation in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have an i3 5005u processor and intel hd graphics 5500 graphics card, which one should i use to render a 3d animation in cycles engine in blender?

Comment: The GPU, of course. But the Intel HD graphics 5500 would be an integrated graphics card, so you won't have an option to render on your GPU, so you will have to render on your CPU since you don't have a discrete graphics card.

Comment: Considering Intel GPUs are not currently supported for Cycles GPU rendering, I don't think you have much of a dilemma

Answer (score 0):

The GPU, of course. But the Intel HD graphics 5500 would be an integrated graphics card, so you won't have an option to render on your GPU, so you will have to render on your CPU since you don't have a discrete graphics card.